# detect gesture on youtube embeded video iphone webview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, youtube

This is my first post here, I have an application with an embedded Youtube video inside a `UIWebView`

I want to detect the users gesture on the `webview` so I can prompt a loading image.
anyone have any idea of a good way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

No need to use any gestures. You just need to use UIWebView Delegate methods.

check this

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate